# Sci-fi book with a galaxy like Andromeda in a planet's sky on the cover

Tags: story-identification, books, cover-art

I remember reading this when I was at school (I pretty much lived in the library and the sci-fi section was my idea of heaven <3) which would have been 1985-ish through to 2000-ish?

But literally the only thing I can remember is the book cover. *facepalm*

I’m pretty sure it was a reddish-pinkish colour, and it had a huge galaxy like the Andromeda Galaxy in the sky of a planet, and it was never truly night, because the galaxy was so bright all the time.

I think it was a hardcover edition that I read, but having said that, it may have been a large paperback library edition, and it looked sort like the style of [this book cover](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60641307-andromeda), with a full galaxy in the sky of a planet (only much bigger), but it had more red/pink tones and was more like daytime, and more of an 80’s-90’s art style.

If this is familiar to anyone, please help me find it again?

Edit: It was a novel, not an anthology.

The galaxy was not pink, I think the sky was pink.

It was a view of the sky from the surface of a planet, the galaxy (definitely Andromeda, Milky Way type galaxy) was clearly visible and quite large looming in the sky like a moon or sun would be, and the galaxy was creating so much light it was never truly dark at night on the planet, which means the cover was related to the story of the novel.

I remember one of the characters commenting on the galaxy and how it was always light in the sky even at night.

Edit 2: Thank you for the suggestion but it is definitely not Foundation’s Edge.

Edit 3: I think it was a standalone novel, not part of a series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any recollection of whether or not it was a collection/anthology as opposed to a novel?  Was the cover picture related to the story?  Was it a view of a galaxy from within another (with foreground stars) or from a point in intergalactic space with only the galaxy itself?  (If the former, are you sure it was a galaxy instead of a planetary nebula?)  Was the galaxy itself pink or was it shown in a pink sky?

Comment: The novel that springs to mind when you mention a galaxy on the cover is [*Foundation's Edge*](https://www.amazon.de/Foundations-Edge-Isaac-Asimov/dp/0345308980) by Isaac Asimov, but the sky isn't pink and the galaxy in the sky isn't a major part of the story.